# Kendo UI grid for Angular dynamic reordering columns

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a Kendo UI for Angular **no** Kendo for JQuery and I have been try to look how to reorder columns dynamically. The [API](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/reordering/) allows reorder by enable it
like this:

```
<kendo-grid [reorderable]="true"...../>
```

But I want tp be able to reorder columns in my code. So far the solution I was doing is having different templates for the grid and change those template but that is very cumbersome. Is there a way or work around to reorder columns dynamically for this new Kendo UI grid for Angular I did not see any in the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how your columns are defined, but I had same problem. Lucky for me, I set my columns with [ngFor](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/hidden/#toc-using-structural-directives). Then I just order array of columns:

```
<kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let column of info?.columns"
                               [field]="column.field"
                               [title]="column.title | translate"
                               [format]="column.format"
                               [filter]="column.filter"
                               [editor]="column.editor"
                               [width]="column.width"
                               [editable]="column.isPrimary"
                               [hidden]="isColumnHidden(column)">
```

Some times ago I ask to implement feature for reading order(not writing). Details are [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/1240). Maybe requesting 2-way binding for order property would be the best. Both problems gone.

Comment: great observation in github. I already added some comments to see if they add that feature. Your idea is the only one that I think can work as a work around for what I need